# How to filter out blank rows from Excel source in Informatica?

Tags: excel, informatica

Using Informatica version 9.6.1 I'm attempting to import an Excel file.  The Excel file has data in rows 1 - 15, every other row is empty.  When using an ODBC connection to the file and importing it, Informatica seems to be having trouble finding the end of the file as it gets to row 1.3 million and then gives the generic "Execution terminated unexpectedly" error message.

I've attempted to add a "Source Filter" to the source qualifier but it either seems to ignore it or it doesn't like the syntax although I'm using basic SQL:

```
WHERE NamedRange.ColumnName = "test"
```

That results in a "Too few parameters. Expected 1" ODBC Excel driver error.

Can the source qualifier filter be used to filter the rows using an Excel source through ODBC?  If so, what is the proper syntax?  If not, are there alternatives that can be done in Informatica?

Comment: Are you using the Named Range? Is it indicated in the Source Qualifier? SQ should use ODBC to read data from the Named Range. It reads as many rows as you define there, regardless of actual data in the sheet.

Comment: Yes, I'm using a named range.  In this case the number of rows to import can vary.

Answer (score 0):

ODBC will read the whole Named Range, I'm afraid. Regardless of actual data. You'll need a Filter Trans after the Source Qualifier to get rid of the empty ones.